# Moving a css shape using .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a graphical presentation for school with css, jquery, and html and I need a rectangle to move across the screen. I've done some research and I've tried using several variations of the `animate` function but it doesn't work out it only sits on the left side of the window.

Here's my code for reference:

```js
var derp = 20;
function scroll() {
  var scrollLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $('#rectangle').animate({
    left: scrollLeft "px",
  }, derp, function() {
    scroll();
  });
}

setInterval(100, scroll());
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#rectangle {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

img,
div,
p,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i think i might have left something out involving jquery but im not sure

Comment: You have one syntax error that I can see. Check your browser's dev console (press F12 then click "console") to see which line it is on. Also, not a syntax error but a logic error, the line `setInterval(100, scroll());` should be `setInterval(scroll, 100);`, i.e., function *name* first (without parentheses after it), *then* the delay in ms. Also, it makes no sense to call `scroll()` from inside the `.animate()` completion callback *as well* as using `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS only.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: anim 3s forwards alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 6;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: But the OP had `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` for the new position...

Comment: thats just to see if it would move @nnnnnn

Comment: @V3ngence91 - We can make educated guesses, but we can't read your mind, so it's not unreasonable to think that you included the `.random()` code because you actually wanted a random movement. If that was just for testing you should edit your question to make that clear (perhaps add a comment to the code at that point), and explain clearly what you actually want instead.

Comment: @Gerard thanks this worked a treat is there anyway to repeat it over n amount of times

Comment: use `infinite ` to `animation: anim 5s infinite forwards;` if you need a no. of time use no. like 4 or some else you want.

Comment: @Lokesh Gupta Thank you both of you you've helped greatly.